# Obter um array com o id e o index de varias divs em jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Olá, sou iniciante em programação principalmente em jquery, mas acredito que seja com ele a única maneira de fazer isso.

Tendo o id e o index das divs, gostaria de obter uma string tipo:

["2:0", "4:1", "3:2", "1:3"] sendo ["id:index"]

Os códigos que estou tentando, no primeiro o resultado sai no console log e não estou conseguindo obter o index e no segundo ele vem com o index mas separados por each em alert

```
<div id="myLists">
   <div class="list" id="2" ></div>
   <div class="list" id="4" ></div>
   <div class="list" id="3" ></div>
   <div class="list" id="1" ></div>
</div>
    
// JEITO 1 - PELO CONSOLE LOG E NAO OBTEM O INDEX
$(function ($) {
   var array = $("#myLists .list").map(function () {
      return $(this).attr('id')
   }).get();
   console.log(array );
});

//JEITO 2 - PELO ALERT 
var array = $('#myLists .list').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('id') ;      
}).get(); 
$.each(array, function( index , pos) {    
   alert( index + ": " + pos );    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brunotrials/3xmqphtr/55/

E após obter essa string, qual seria o melhor caminho para enviar para php? Porque após isso já tenho como gravar no banco de dados.

Obrigado

Comment: olá Bruno, adicione o código html/javascript na pergunta, fica mais fácil de visualizar, pode copiar direto do jsfiddle, aqui tbm funciona :)

Comment: JQuery é js e roda na máquina enquanto que PHP roda no servidor, logo os dois não se comunicam. Teria que enviar as informações pra uma página PHP via Ajax

Comment: Você pode utilizar `each` no lugar de `map` e modificar a iteração no loop each para criar uma string no formato que deseja [id:index]: aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gwjq9rxL/. Além disso, no exemplo já há uma forma de como enviar para o PHP, que nada mais é do que utilizar o Ajax.

Answer (score -2):

Para obter a string no formato "id:index", você pode usar o método map do jQuery para percorrer as divs e criar uma nova array com as strings desejadas. Dentro do callback do map, você pode acessar o índice de cada div usando o segundo parâmetro da função de callback.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código que deve fazer o que você precisa:

```
$(function () {
   var array = $("#myLists .list").map(function (index) {
      return $(this).attr('id') + ':' + index;
   }).get();
   console.log(array);
});
```

Este código deve imprimir a seguinte array no console:

```
["2:0", "4:1", "3:2", "1:3"]
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá Victor! Foi quase isso, fiz uma modificação no seu código e agora funcionou
$(function ($) {
  var array = $("#myLists .list").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('id') + ':' + $(this).index()
    }).get();
    console.log(array );
});


obrigado!!